# PhpMyAdmin is not able to load the table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table where I have 1.5 million records (680 MB). When I am trying to open this table in PHPMyAdmin it is not able to load

Comment: Do you receive errors or problems?

Comment: Yes, I got the 'timeout' error after 600 secs and then the server is down. and this is happening with only one table

Comment: Do you have indexing in your table?

Comment: I am trying to add index but it is not letting me add

Answer (score 0):

- Edit config.default.php file in PHPMyAdmin
- For Xampp it is located at

please go to `xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\config.default.php`

look for `$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 600;`

Change it to a higher value like 5000

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the `ExecTimeLimit` inside `config.default.php`file.

Default value is `600`. Edit it with `0` (no limit execution time):

```
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;
```